# datetime vs dateime2, qual é o melhor?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, code-first

Estou implementando um projeto novo, usando **EF6 CodeFirst**, o EF6 cria meu banco de dados *Sql-Server*, com as colunas de data como tipo *datetime*.

Qual seria a diferença entre *datetime* e *datetime2*, e qual o mais indiciado para ser usado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATETIME2` tem um range de data maior que `DATETIME`:

**DATETIME**: 01/01/1753 E 31/12/9999
**DATETIME2**: 01/01/0001 A 31/12/9999

A documentação do MSDN recomenda usar DATETIME2 (a partir do **SQL Server 2008**):

> Use os tipos de dados time, date, datetime2 e datetimeoffset para o
>   novo trabalho. Esses tipos estão de acordo com o SQL padrão. Eles são
>   mais portáteis. time, datetime2 e datetimeoffset fornecem mais
>   precisão de segundos. datetimeoffset é compatível com fuso horário
>   para aplicativos implantados globalmente.

Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql