# Como alterar o EF6 para criar campos DateTime como datetime2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Estou trabalhando com **EF6 Code-first", banco de dados SQL-Server.

Me deparei com o seguinte erro, ao salvar um objeto com propriedade DateTime.

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   ↵The statement has been terminated.

Pesquisando, verifiquei que o EF6 por default, cria as propriedades do Tipo *DateTime* do *C#*, como o tipo *datetime* do *Sql-Server*.

Fiz algumas pesquisas para entender a diferença, até mesmo criei uma pergunta sobre isso aqui no stack [datetime vs datetime2. qual é a melhor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289312/datetime-vs-dateime2-qual-%C3%A9-o-melhor), na resposta do colega, ele destacou a sugestão na própria documentação da microsoft, indicando o uso do datetime2. Conforme menciono abaixo..

> Use os tipos de dados time, date, datetime2 e datetimeoffset para o novo trabalho. Esses tipos estão de acordo com o SQL padrão. Eles são mais portáteis. time, datetime2 e datetimeoffset fornecem mais precisão de segundos. datetimeoffset é compatível com fuso horário para aplicativos implantados globalmente. Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql

Baseado nisso, eu quero saber como fazer com que o EF6, passe a usar o *datetime2*, sem ter que configurar propriedade a propriedade. Que seria da seguinte forma:

```
Property(m => m.Created)
        .HasColumnName("Created")
        .HasColumnType("datetime2")
        .IsRequired();
```

Eu quero uma configuração global.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu banco?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic é o V12 do azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `Context` você pode configurar para que todas propriedades do tipo `DateTime` sejam `datetime2`. Para isso é necessário dar um `override` o método `OnModelCreating` o código seria assim:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {            
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
            .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No meu caso, eu defini isso no método `OnModelCreating`, acrescentando essa linha:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```

Foi uma resposta dessa pergunta no SO (não a aceita, mas a que me ajudou): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687408/how-to-switch-to-datetime2-in-enitity-framework-sql-server-2008-project